# How to get data without editText from USB Barcode Scanner on Android?

Tags: android, usb, barcode-scanner

I have USB Barcode Scanner, and I want to get result after scanning without EditText. I'm trying use onKeyUp/onKeyDown methods, but I get only few symbols. Now I'm trying use Invisible EditText, but it not work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `TextWatcher`. But you need an `EditText`, you can make it invisible in your layout. It will be easier than key up/down methods.

Basically it listens for the incoming characters and you can implement the methods like `afterTextChanged`, `onTextChanged`, where you can get the whole string, or particular character, etc.. Read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: but TextWatcher work with EditText, I haven't it in Activity

Comment: No, TextWatcher does not need EditText, I will add an example now.

Comment: Sorry, you're right you need an EditText. But you can use a trick and make it invisible with no height and width, so you can listen to that. That's how I've used it in a project.

Comment: Thank you, after 5 hours I solved this problem, but I use EditText with onKeyUp method, and set focus on editText  in onCreate